# sort by hex value

Tags: sort, coreutils

Using coreutils `sort`, how can I sort numerically by a hexadecimal value (field)?  I was expecting something along the lines of

```
sort -k3,3x file_to_sort
```

however, such an `x` does not exist.

Edit: Best solution I came up with so far is:

```
{ echo ibase=16; cut -d' ' -f3 file_to_sort; } |
  bc | paste -d: - file_to_sort | sort -t: -k1,1n | cut -d: -f2-
```

where the `cut -d' ' -f3` isolates the search field (this is `-k3,3` — this may vary, of course), and `bc` does conversion to decimal (requires upper-case hex, without `0x` prefix, matching my case).  Then I join, sort, and split columns.

Minimal sample input:

```
5 hhf 25
3 ezh ae
1 hdh d12
2 ukr 9f
4 jjk 7
```

Expected output (file sorted by `hex` third column):

```
4 jjk 7
5 hhf 25
2 ukr 9f
3 ezh ae
1 hdh d12
```

Comment: `-k3,3`? You have hex nubers staring with 0x and all of the same length? No mix of upper/lowercase? If yes, they should sort right when interpreted as strings. Maybe you can show us some example data?

Comment: @yeti: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Feature request: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2017-08/msg00035.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution in `perl`:

```
$ perl -anle '
    push @h, [$F[-1],$_];
    END {
        print for map  { $_->[0] }
                  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                  map  { [$_->[1],hex($_->[0])] } @h;
    }
' file
4 jjk 7
5 hhf 25
2 ukr 9f
3 ezh ae
1 hdh d12
```

**Explanation**

- While processing file, we create an array of array `@h`, each of its element is an array reference `[$F[-1],$_]`, with first element is the hex value to compare, and the second element is the whole line.
- In `END` block, we use [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

  - With each element of `@h`, create an anonymous array, contains the whole line ( `$_->[1]` the second element of each array ref in `@h` ) and the hex value to compare `hex($_->[0])]`
  - Sort above array base on the hex value `$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]`
  - Get the first element of each array ref in sorted array `map  { $_->[0] }`
     then print the result.

**Update**

With @Joseph R's suggestion, without using Schwartzian Transform:

```
$ perl -anle '
    push @h, [hex($F[-1]),$_];
    END {
        print $_->[1] for
            sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @h;
    }
' file
```

**Update 2**

After reading stefan's comment, I think this can call `direct`:

```
$ perl -e '
    print sort {hex((split(/\s+/,$a))[-1]) <=> hex((split(/\s+/,$b))[-1])} <>;
' file
4 jjk 7
5 hhf 25
2 ukr 9f
3 ezh ae
1 hdh d12
```

Comment: +1 but why not just : `print for sort { hex $a->[-1] <=> hex $b->[-1] } @h`? The `hex` operator is hardly expensive enough to warrant a Schwartzian, isn't it?

Comment: @JosephR.: Maybe, but a Schwartzian is more flexible and work in all case. I think we can have another solution by compute the hex value while processing, will update my answer soon.

Comment: Cool solution.  Did not know this pattern had a name: decorate-sort-undecorate.  See my comment above.

Comment: @stefan: see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gnouc: yes, your 2nd Update definitively qualifies as direct wrt. my initial imagination.

Comment: I don't understand why it works with `hex()` for edit#2 and not simply like this (removing `hex()` : `perl -e 'print sort { (split(/\s+/,$a))[-1] <=> (split(/\s+/,$b))[-1] } <>'` file

Answer (score 9):

I use this example data:

```
1 hdh d12
2 ukr 9f
3 ezh ae
4 jjk 7
5 hhf 25
```

The idea is to create a new version of this data with the sort field in decimal form. I.e. `awk` converts it, prepends it to each line, the result is sorted, and as last step the added field is removed:

```
awk '{val="0x" $3; sub("^0x0x","0x",val); print strtonum(val),$0 ;}' file | 
  sort -n | 
  sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Which results in this output:

```
4 jjk 7
5 hhf 25
2 ukr 9f
3 ezh ae
1 hdh d12
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty cool solution.  Sorry that I did not post my edit earlier, it follows a similar approach using cut+paste.  I was hoping for a more direct solution though...

Comment: @stefan What counts as "direct"? Does the solution have to use `sort`?

Comment: @Joseph “What counts as "direct"?” is the right question.  Basically all solutions so far (Hauke's, Gnouc's below, and mine) do something similar: Decode the hex value, attach result to the lines, sort by it, and remove it.  I was looking for something not using the [decorate-sort-undecorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern.

Both solutions are superior to mine, in that tey work in a pipeline.
I've chosen this one because I'd personally rather use awk (the
smaller hammer) than Perl for this kind of task.

Comment: I have moved my choice of an answer to #3 below, because of Gnouc's second update.

Answer (score 3):

Input

```
$ cat /tmp/input
0x45 aaa 333
0x50 dd 33
0x4 bbbb 444
0x456 cc 22
0x5 eee 1111
```

Sorting one liner

```
$ gawk  --non-decimal-data '{ dec = sprintf("%d", $1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/input | sort -n -k 1 | cut -f2- -d' '
0x4 bbbb 444
0x5 eee 1111
0x45 aaa 333
0x50 dd 33
0x456 cc 22
```

Sorting step by step

Step 1: Add a new first column with the decimal representation of the hex number.

```
$ gawk  --non-decimal-data '{ dec = sprintf("%d", $1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/input 
69 0x45 aaa 333
80 0x50 dd 33
4 0x4 bbbb 444
1110 0x456 cc 22
5 0x5 eee 1111
```

Step 2: Sort the lines numerically on the first field.

```
$ gawk  --non-decimal-data '{ dec = sprintf("%d", $1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/input | sort -n -k 1
4 0x4 bbbb 444
5 0x5 eee 1111
69 0x45 aaa 333
80 0x50 dd 33
1110 0x456 cc 22
```

Step 3: Remove the first column.

```
$ gawk  --non-decimal-data '{ dec = sprintf("%d", $1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/input | sort -n -k 1 | cut -f2- -d' '
0x4 bbbb 444
0x5 eee 1111
0x45 aaa 333
0x50 dd 33
0x456 cc 22
```

Comment: [GAWK's manual for `--non-decimal-data` warns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_002dn-option) _CAUTION: This option can severely break old programs.  Use with care.  Also note that this option may disappear in a future version of 'gawk'_. `strtonum()` is a safer alternative: `gawk '{ dec = strtonum($1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/input | sort -n -k1 | cut -f2- -d' '`.

Answer (score 1):

adapted from: http://www.unix.com/302548935-post6.html?s=b4b6b3ed50b6831717f6429113302ad6

:file-to-sort:

```
6F993B
954B29
A23F2F
BFA91D
C68C15
8F322F
5A6D40
6D512C
9D9D63
B4B823
A0641C
A79716
A18518
```

Command:

```
awk '{printf("%050s\t%s\n", toupper($0), $0)}' file-to-sort | LC_COLLATE=C sort -k1,1 | cut -f2
```

Output:

```
C68C15
BFA91D
B4B823
A79716
A23F2F
A18518
A0641C
9D9D63
954B29
8F322F
6F993B
6D512C
5A6D40
```

--where the toupper($0) "upgrades" lowercase letters so they'll sort first (not sure that's necessary though?)